# python json вывод нужного элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Пытаюсь понять как вывести из json нужный элемент, а именно вывести из этих 3х второй, к примеру, и все данные о нем.

```
[
  {
    "title": "q",
    "producerName": "q",
    "producerLName": "q",
    "year": "1111",
    "country": "Q",
    "cost": "111111111",
    "income": "11111",
    "profit": "111111"
  },
  {
    "title": "w",
    "producerName": "w",
    "producerLName": "w",
    "year": "2222",
    "country": "W",
    "cost": "222222222",
    "income": "22222",
    "profit": "222222"
  },
  {
    "title": "e",
    "producerName": "e",
    "producerLName": "e",
    "year": "3333",
    "country": "E",
    "cost": "333333333",
    "income": "33333",
    "profit": "333333"
  }
]
```

Comment: А что не получается? покажите пример кода, покажите, что с ним не работает?

Comment: рекомендую почитать лутца. он очень хорошо описывает как работать со словарём, списком и модулями в том числе

Comment: внешний файл говорите... хорошо. тогда проверте чтоб файл с json имел в самом конце .py и (это очень важно) запомните название файла. поместите его в тот же каталог где и ваша прога для парсинга этого json. в проге в начале файла добавте import file_name где file_name это название файла с json. и всё, вы можете теперь обращатся к этому json'у как я описывал ранее, только обращатся к нему придётся через имя file_name (file_name - имя йфайла:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

json_str = """
[
    {
        "title": "q",
        "year": "1111"
    },
    {
        "title": "w",
        "year": "2222"
    },
    {
        "title": "e",
        "year": "3333"
    }
]"""

items = json.loads(json_str)

item = items[1]
print(item['title'], item['year'])  # w 2222
print(item)  # {'title': 'w', 'year': '2222'}
```

---

**UPD.** на основе дополнения от автора добавлю пример парсинга json из одного `py` файла и получения результата из другого.

Показанные файлы в одной папке хранить.

**my_load_json.py**:

```
import json

json_str = """
[
    {
        "title": "q",
        "year": "1111"
    },
    {
        "title": "w",
        "year": "2222"
    },
    {
        "title": "e",
        "year": "3333"
    }
]"""

items = json.loads(json_str)
```

**main.py**:

```
from my_load_json import items

print(items)  # {'title': 'w', 'year': '2222'}
print(item['title'], item['year'])  # w 2222
```

---

**UPD.** кое-кто расчехлил минусомет и прошелся по всем ответам и вопросу. Мне интересно было бы узнать чем мой ответ не понравился :)

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня были проблемы именно с такими примерами, я где не искал, json задают сразу в файле, а мне нужно на основе готового, работать с данными, которые находятся в отдельном файле

Comment: с этого стоило начинать))) проверте чтоб файл с json имен окончание .py и для простоты находился в том же каталоге из которого вы к нему хотите достучатся. в импортируйте файл с json в вашей проге import file_name (без .py) потом можете обращатся к json через имя файла

Comment: @daedra, добавьте в вопрос эту информацию ) Расширил ответ

Comment: @gil9red что то не то, как оно видит, что выводить если нету указателя и тд :\

Comment: @daedra, в питоне нет указателей. Запускайте main.py чтобы был виден результат

Answer (score 1):

Вот смотрите, все эти json"ы помещены в "[" и "]" - это очень хорошо, так как это стандартный тип данных на пайтоне и называется он "список" или "List". его преимущества в том, что он итерируемый, а потому можно получить его длину:

```
print (len(...))
```

По нему можно пройтись циклом:

```
for x in ...:
```

Из этого всего вытекает то, что можно обратиться к конкретному элементу по его порядковому номеру (нумерация начинается с 0). И теперь ответ на ваш вопрос - вторым элементов в списке будет "1"! Чтобы до него достучаться просто к имени переменной с этим всем списком добавьте [1] и всё.

Но я забегаю на перёд и даю Вам большую подсказку чтобы Вы не задавали встречный вопрос "как получить конкретный элемент..." Вы получите словарь (или что-то очень на него похожее) и обращение к элементам уже будет через имя, а не через его порядковый номер. Более детально как работать со списком и словарём ищите в интернете, материалов там полно. Не задавайте больше подобный вопросов.

И напоследок: чтобы понять с каким типом данных вам придётся работать в конкретный момент времени:

```
print (type(...))
```

Comment: Официальная политика партии поощряет даже такие вопросы. Целые войны на этот счёт идут, но пока что мы не победили, поэтому... не нужно призывать учить учебник, а просто отвечать. Или мимо проходить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, избегайте при ответе рассуждений на общие темы, напрямую не относящихся к вопросу. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Ну как бы тут всё как у стандартных python классов (вывод второго элемента):

```
import json
import pprint

# Читаем JSON из строки
json_str = """
[
    {
        "title": "q",
        "producerName": "q",
        "producerLName": "q",
        "year": "1111",
        "country": "Q",
        "cost": "111111111",
        "income": "11111",
        "profit": "111111"
    },
    {
        "title": "w",
        "producerName": "w",
        "producerLName": "w",
        "year": "2222",
        "country": "W",
        "cost": "222222222",
        "income": "22222",
        "profit": "222222"
    },
    {
        "title": "e",
        "producerName": "e",
        "producerLName": "e",
        "year": "3333",
        "country": "E",
        "cost": "333333333",
        "income": "33333",
        "profit": "333333"
    }
]"""
list_obj = json.loads(json_str)
pprint.pprint(list_obj[1])

# Читаем внешний JSON
with open("example.json") as file:
    json_str = file.read()

list_obj = json.loads(json_str)
pprint.pprint(list_obj[1])
```

Или я не очень понял в чём проблема...

Comment: Код неправильный

Comment: ага. Опечатка) Исправил)

Comment: вот так лучше )

Comment: @ДмитрийИгоревич Спасибо за ваш пример, но не могли бы вы показать как задавать json не в основном файле, а работать с готовым используя данные с другого файла

Comment: @daedra, Поправил код примера, добавив вариант с внешним JSON в файле.